# How do I get the element after my horizontal css navigation bar to appear below it?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a css unordered list to make a site navigation bar, using `display: inline`, `display: block`, and `float: left`.  The next element that I put after the navigation bar is placed to the right of it.  How can I align the next element so that it is displayed below?

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/test.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">One1</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Four</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div><h2>Heading</h2></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The css:

```
ul.nav, ul li.nav {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li.nav {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

a.nav {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
}

a:hover.nav {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `clear: left;` on the div after your list.  This should then clear the element to appear below your unordered list.

Edit: should actually read `clear: left;` although using `clear: both;` will also work

Answer (score 0):

Use a float clear and then size and position the heading div below it.  If you give it a width larger than the space to the right of the nav bar, it should automatically drop down.

CSS:

```
.clear { clear:both; }
#heading { position:relative; margin:0px auto; width:980px; }
```

HTML after nav:

```
<div class="clear"></div>    
<div id="heading">Heading</div>
```